# VBA - Convert string to datetime to compare with date in SQL

Tags: sql, vba, adodb

Probably a simple question, but I haven't been able to find an answer on any forums yet.

I am using VBA to push data into SQL from an open source, and what I need my code to do is check the timestamp of the most recent data in SQL to determine if it needs to retrieve more data, or it is most up to date.

By using ADODB I can retrieve the latest date from SQL as follows

```
print latest_date
13/07/2021 8:14:50 PM
```

And the date from the data I want to collect as

```
print resource_date
'2021-07-13 20:14:50'
```

As you can see, the `resource_date` is a string, and the `latest_date` is an item from an ADODB recordset. These can't be compared in an If statement to see if they're the same.

I've tried using `CDate()` but I get mismatched type errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are bothering with formatted values. VBA stores date in a `Double`, see e.g. `cdbl(now)`. You need to check how your SQL db stores the date (most probably in double, too, but the zero date can be different). Get that data, adjust the zero points if necessary, and you can compare them easily.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the text date to a *true date value* and use *DateDiff* to compare, for example by the second ("s"):

```vb
If DateDiff("s", print latest_date, CDate(resource_date)) > 0
    ' latest_date is earlier than resource_date.
End If
```